# Stop CSS & Jquery Slideshow from looping

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, infinite-loop

I'm new to JQuery and don't know how to stop my jquery and css slideshow from looping. Here's all the syntax:

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <div>
    <img src="Slide1.gif">     
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="Slide2.gif">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="Slide3.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow { 
margin: 50px auto; 
position: relative; 
width: 755px; 
height: 410px; 
padding: 10px; 
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
position: absolute; 
top: 10px; 
left: 10px; 
right: 10px; 
bottom: 10px; 
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(2000)
.next()
.fadeIn(2000)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

Can someone please selp me? Any would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure what I did or what to do, I'm kind of new to jquery. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable assigned to your interval function

```
var slideshowInterval = setInterval(function() { 
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(2000)
.next()
.fadeIn(2000)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

So when you want to stop it, just call the function clearInterval :

```
clearInterval(slideshowInterval);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly @isThisLove. I will certainly try that now.

Comment: i'm assuming your slideshow is working, code here is to stop it.